# Setting rootViewController for ipad 3.2 doesnt work

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

i did a simple navigationbased app.
it works on iphone very well, but it doesnt work on ipad 3.2 simulator and device.

in applicationdidfinish event;

```
MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[viewController release];
```

it says for this line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

**[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c22dd0**

but it works on ipad 4.2 and over.

how can i solve it for ipad 3.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIWindow did not have a rootViewController property in iOS < 4.0. Therefore, you will need to check the version (google it) and then either set the rootViewController, or add the navigationController's `view` as a subview to the window as below, based on what version your user is running.:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

quick edit: to check if you can use the rootViewController property, you can check if `[self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewController)]` returns TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: great, it works for all iOS version. i think i dont need to check version. because i dont set the view controller in IB. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is (don't forget ":"!):

```
if ( [self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:)] )
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
else
    [self.window addSubview: self.tabBarController.view];
```